# Inserting multiple values into a vector at specific positions

Tags: c++, vector

Say I have a vector of integers like this `std::vector<int> _data;`
I know that if I want to remove multiple items from `_data`, then I can simply call

```
_data.erase( std::remove_if( _data.begin(), _data.end(), [condition] ), _data.end() );
```

Which is much faster than `erase`ing multiple elements, as less movement of data is required within the `vector`. I'm wondering if there's something similar for insertions.

For example, if I have the following pairs

```
auto pair1 = { _data.begin() + 5, 5 };
auto pair2 = { _data.begin() + 12, 12 };
```

Can I insert both of these in one iteration using some existing `std` function? I know I can do something like:

```
_data.insert( pair2.first, pair2.second );
_data.insert( pair1.first, pair1.second );
```

But this is (very) slow for large vectors (talking 100,000+ elements).

EDIT: Basically, I have a custom set (and map) which use a `vector` as the underlying containers. I know I can just use `std::set` or `std::map`, but the number of traversals I do far outweighs the insertion/removals. Switching from a `set` and `map` to this custom set/map already cut 20% of run-time off. Currently though, insertions take approximately 10% of the remaining run time, so reducing that is important.

The order is also required, unfortunately. As much as possible, I use the `unordered_` versions, but in some places the order does matter.

Comment: maybe `reserve()` or `resie()` would help?

Comment: The vector's internal capacity is already sufficient (pre-allocated around 200,000)

Comment: If you are inserting a lot in the middle then simply you should not use `std::vector` but something else. What is "something else"? It relay depends on actual application - problem your code solves. So basically your question suffers from [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: There's no standard library algorithm for this from what I can tell. You'll probably have to write your own.

Comment: @walnut, sorry, was just an example. I've switched the order.

Comment: The impending doom of the shift is already a foregone hit. I don't see how this will be available. They're different use cases entirely regardless. In the case of remove+erase, it is the value (i.e. the "what") of the elements dictating their pending removal/ejection. In your insertion case, it is the *location* (i.e. the "where").  You may just need a different container. Specialized containers are built for such things (like skip lists, etc).

Comment: @MarekR, it's mimicking the functionality of a `set` by using an underlying container of `vector`. `set`'s traversal is far too slow. I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: Do you need the ordering of a set? I.e. is an [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) possibly on the menu ?

Comment: Updated the question with some additional details.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create another vector with capacity equal to the original size plus the number of the elements being inserted and then do an insert loop with no reallocations, O(N) complexity:

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T> insert_elements(std::vector<T> const& v, std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::size_t, T>> new_elements) {
    std::vector<T> u;
    u.reserve(v.size() + new_elements.size());
    auto src = v.begin();
    size_t copied = 0;
    for(auto const& element : new_elements) {
        auto to_copy = element.first - copied;
        auto src_end = src + to_copy;
        u.insert(u.end(), src, src_end);
        src = src_end;
        copied += to_copy;
        u.push_back(element.second);
    }
    u.insert(u.end(), src, v.end());
    return u;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1, 3, 5};
    for(auto e : insert_elements(v, {{1,2}, {2,4}}))
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I like you're answer. I would either have to do some modifications to use iterators instead of the positions, or I could wrap it, and use `distance`. I found a slightly better way which doesn't use iterators or positions though, and instead uses insertion sorting. EDIT: I actually just compared it to `vector.insert` and both are slower than the `vector`'s. :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we need some assumptions. Let `old_end` be a reverse iterator to the last element of your vector. Assume that your `_data` has been resized to exactly fit both its current content and what you want to insert. Assume that `inp` is a container of `std::pair` containing your data to be inserted that is ordered reversely (so first the element that is to be inserted at the hindmost position and so on). Then we can do:

```cpp
std::merge(old_end, _data.rend(), inp.begin(), inp.end(), data.rend(), [int i = inp.size()-1](const &T t, const &std::pair<Iter, T> p) mutable {
    if( std::distance(_data.begin(), p.first) == i ) {
         --i;
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But I think that is not more clear than using a good old `for`. The problem with the stl-algorithms is that the predicates work on values and not on iterators thats a bit annoying for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take:

```
template<class Key, class Value>
class LinearSet
{
public:
    using Node = std::pair<Key, Value>;

    template<class F>
    void insert_at_multiple(F&& f)
    {
        std::queue<Node> queue;
        std::size_t index = 0;
        for (auto it = _kvps.begin(); it != _kvps.end(); ++it)
        {
            // The container size is left untouched here, no iterator invalidation.
            if (std::optional<Node> toInsert = f(index))
            {
                queue.push(*it);
                *it = std::move(*toInsert);
            }
            else
            {
                ++index;
                // Replace current node with queued one.
                if (!queue.empty())
                {
                    queue.push(std::move(*it));
                    *it = std::move(queue.front());
                    queue.pop();
                }
            }
        }

        // We now have as many displaced items in the queue as were inserted,
        // add them to the end.
        while (!queue.empty())
        {
            _kvps.emplace_back(std::move(queue.front()));
            queue.pop();
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<Node> _kvps;
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EStKgQ

This is a linear time algorithm that doesn't need to know the number of inserted elements a priori. For each index, it asks for an element to insert there. If it gets one, it pushes the corresponding existing vector element to a queue and replaces it with the new one. Otherwise, it extracts the current item to the back of the queue and puts the item at the front of the queue into the current position (noop if no elements were inserted yet). Note that the vector size is left untouched during all this. Only at the end do we push back all items still in the queue.

Note that the indices we use for determining inserted item locations here are all **pre-insertion**. I find this a point of potential confusion (and it is a limitation - you can't add an element at the very end with this algorithm. Could be remedied by calling `f` during the second loop too, working on that...).

---

Here's a version that allows inserting arbitrarily many elements at the end (and everywhere else). It passes **post-insertion indices** to the functor!

```
template<class F>
void insert_at_multiple(F&& f)
{
    std::queue<Node> queue;
    std::size_t index = 0;
    for (auto it = _kvps.begin(); it != _kvps.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (std::optional<Node> toInsert = f(index))
            queue.push(std::move(*toInsert));

        if (!queue.empty())
        {
            queue.push(std::move(*it));
            *it = std::move(queue.front());
            queue.pop();
        }

        ++index;
    }

    // We now have as many displaced items in the queue as were inserted,
    // add them to the end.
    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        if (std::optional<Node> toInsert = f(index))
        {
            queue.push(std::move(*toInsert));
        }

        _kvps.emplace_back(std::move(queue.front()));
        queue.pop();
        ++index;
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/DMuCtJ

Again, this leaves potential for confusion over what it means to insert at indices 0 and 1 (do you end up with an original element in between the two? In the first snippet you would, in the second you wouldn't). Can you insert at the same index multiple times? With pre-insertion indices that makes sense, with post-insertion indices it doesn't. You could also write this in terms of passing the current `*it` (i.e. key value pair) to the functor, but that alone seems not too useful...

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt I made, which inserts in reverse order. I did get rid of the iterators/indices for this.

```
template<class T>
void insert( std::vector<T> &vector, const std::vector<T> &values ) {
    size_t last_index = vector.size() - 1;
    vector.resize( vector.size() + values.size() ); // relies on T being default constructable
    size_t move_position = vector.size() - 1;

    size_t last_value_index = values.size() - 1;
    size_t values_size = values.size();

    bool isLastIndex = false;

    while ( !isLastIndex && values_size ) {
        if ( values[last_value_index] > vector[last_index] ) {
            vector[move_position] = std::move( values[last_value_index--] );
            --values_size;
        } else {
            isLastIndex = last_index == 0;
            vector[move_position] = std::move( vector[last_index--] );
        }
        --move_position;
    }

    if ( isLastIndex && values_size ) {
        while ( values_size ) {
            vector[move_position--] = std::move( values[last_value_index--] );
            --values_size;
        }
    }
}
```

Tried with ICC, Clang, and GCC on Godbolt, and vector's `insert` was faster (for 5 numbers inserted). On my machine, MSVC, same result but less severe. I also compared with Maxim's version from his answer. I realize using Godbolt isn't a good method for comparison, but I don't have access to the 3 other compilers on my current machine.

https://godbolt.org/z/vjV2wA

Results from my machine:

> My insert: 659us
>   Maxim insert: 712us
>   Vector insert: 315us

Godbolt's ICC

> My insert: 470us
>   Maxim insert: 139us
>   Vector insert: 127us

Godbolt's GCC

> My insert: 815us
>   Maxim insert: 97us
>   Vector insert: 97us

Godbolt's Clang:

> My insert: 477us
>   Maxim insert: 188us
>   Vector insert: 96us